# Mongoose - find() with multiple ids that are the same

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I were to perform this query with mongoose;

```
Schema.find({
    _id: {
        $in: ['abcd1234', 'abcd1234', 'abcd1234']
    }
});
```

The query will only return something like:

```
[{
    'property1': 'key1',
    'property2': 'key2'
}]
```

With the array only having one object, obviously because I passed in all the same id's. However, I actually want duplicate objects returned. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mongo itself will only return objects with no duplicates. But you can then build an array of objects with duplicates from that.

For example, if `array` is the array of objects returned my Mongo - in this case:

```
var array = [{
    _id: 'abcd1234',
    property1: 'key1',
    property2: 'key2'
}];
```

and `ids` is your list of IDs that you want with duplicates - in your case:

```
var ids = ['abcd1234', 'abcd1234', 'abcd1234'];
```

then you can do:

```
var objects = {};
array.forEach(o => objects[o._id] = o);
var dupArray = ids.map(id => objects[id]);
```

Now `dupArray` should contain the objects with duplicates.

Full example:

```
var ids = ['abcd1234', 'abcd1234', 'abcd1234'];
Schema.find({_id: {$in: ids}}, function (err, array) {
  if (err) {
    // handle error
  } else {
    var objects = {};
    array.forEach(o => objects[o._id] = o);
    var dupArray = ids.map(id => objects[id]);
    // here you have objects with duplicates in dupArray:
    console.log(dupArray);
  }
});
```